# Mac Script Question: adding colon as a String

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to add a colon after the display model. Basically I would like the output to be:

`model: serialnumber`

I'm having trouble adding `:` as a string.

My script is written in a way where it only gives an output if an external monitor exists.

```
#!/bin/sh

#sets serial = serialnumber

serial=`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -i "Display Serial Number" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | cut -d " " -f 4`

#sets displayModel = model serialnumber

displayModel=`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/{print x}; {x=$0};/Framebuffer Depth:/{getline;print$3}' | sed -e 's/^ *//g;s/://g'`

#if serial exists, echo model serialnumber

if [ ! -z "$serial" ]

then

#Outputs: model serialnumber

echo "<result>$displayModel</result>"

fi
```

Comment: thank you for making my question look a lot neater it is greatly appreciated @pkamb

Comment: echo "$displayModel": "$serial"

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I appreciate the help, but I believe that will output: 

model serialnumber: serialnumber

Comment: Try `echo "Text and stuff, ${variable1}:${variable2}"`

Answer (score 1):

-Use `printf` to keep each model and serialnumber output on the same line.

-Using `:` was not working but using `|` instead will work.

-I also added a `,`  at the end.

displayModel = system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/{printf x; `printf" | "`}; {x=$0};/Framebuffer Depth:/{getline;printf$4; `print", "`}' | sed -e 's/^ *//g;s/://g'

-Output is:

`model | serialnumber,`

`model | serialnumber,`